# Inno script to identify SQL Server instances installed on client system and skip installing instance if already installed

Tags: sql-server, inno-setup

I am creating a package using inno script and want to install SQL Server `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU` on the client's machine. I want code which determines installed SQL Server instances (`MSSQL$MYSQL` and `MSSQLSERVER`) on the target system. If the instances are already installed, then the script should skip installing the instances again.

I am using following shell script to find instances and calling it by batch file but it is not working.

```
$server = $env:computername  

$object = Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $server  | where {($_.name -like "MSSQL$*" -or $_.name -like "MSSQLSERVER" -or $_.name -like "SQL Server (*") -and $_.name -notlike "*helper*" -and $_.name -notlike "*Launcher*"}

if ($object)
{
    echo " One OR More Instances running..."

    $instInfo= $object |select Name,StartMode,State, Status 
}
else
{
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\sql\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"

    echo " No SQL Instances running..."
}
```

Is there any Inno script which can find number of SQL Server instances installed?